# MultiQueries in Sphinx in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, sphinx

```
$query = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"~100';
$query2 = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"~300'
$query3 = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"/3';
$query4 = '@(name,email,biot) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"/1';
```

I want to execute this in one query! If I use the "|" OR operator, it takes approx 2minutes to display the results!

Is there anyway using multiquery in sphinxapi I can combine all these queries into one?

Comment: What exactly is this query supposed to do?

Comment: This is supposed to search "$this->passedArgs['name']" inside name,email,bio using sphinx. the problem is using quorum and proximity operators in one single query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the single query using OR(|) operator, Sphinx wasn't returning accurate results. Later found out AddQuery function which helped me in getting results from multiple queries and merging into one.

I can even specify separate indexes for each query. Refer [Sphinx Documentation AddQuery](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-addquery)

```
    $cl->AddQuery('@(name,email,bio) "one two" ~100', 'dist'); 
    $cl->AddQuery('@(name,email,bio) "one two" ~300', 'dist'); 
    $cl->AddQuery('@(name,email,bio) "one two" ~300', 'dist'); 
    $cl->AddQuery('@(name,email,bio) "one two" /3', 'dist'); 
    $cl->AddQuery('@(name,email,bio) "one two" ~/1', 'metaphone dist'); 
    $result = $cl->RunQueries();
    echo "<pre>",print_r($result),"</pre>";
```

I did SetIndexWeights call to prioritize multiple indexes that I have used. Refer [Sphinx Document SetIndexWeights](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setindexweights)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
@(name,email,bio) ( "one two"~100 | "one two"~300 | "one two"/3 | "one two"/1 )
```

Might be a bit quicker.

Comment: Well, this works but search results arent accurate. Is there anyway i could rank the search results for a particular query!
Ex:
 "one two"~100  - Rank higher and display first ......
 "one two"~300 - Second

Comment: is there anyway i could do this http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.2/multi-queries.html for my 4 queries?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand (from your comment), you're looking for `$this->passedArgs['name']` in the `@(name,email,bio)` fields, within `~100` characters **OR** `~300` characters **OR** having at least `/3` words matching **OR** at least `/1` word matching?

Why not then split it out to two different queries, the most limiting first:

```
$query = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"~100';
$query4 = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"/1';
```

perform those queries, `|`d together. If you get no results from it, perform the below query, also `|`d together.

```
$query2 = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"~300'
$query3 = '@(name,email,bio) ' . '"' . $this->passedArgs['name'] . '"/3';
```

Comment: Thats what I have done and it takes TWO MINUTES to display results! the database is huge (7GB). Sometimes it doesn't show results, just keeps loading! Is there any other way searchd could optimize multiple queries!

Comment: The best table I have for comparison is only 1.7G, but a query like yours above performs in about 1/100th of a second. Can you confirm an example of the actual query sent to searchd?

Comment: If i use the OR operator, the results aren't accurate! Its faster but not accurate. I am displaying each query result individually. EX: Query1 and then display result, Query2 and then display result....this is without using OR operator.

Comment: I'm confused. So you're saying you're performing *4* different searches, and combined, they take over 2 minutes?

Comment: Yes .I am displaying each query result individually, one after the other but using the OR operator doesn't yield accurate results, I want the results to be displayed in order! if query1 display results if its null move on to query 2 or move on to query 3! Using the OR operator isn't yielding proper results.